# Reusable styles with StencilJS / web components

Tags: web-component, stenciljs

I'm new to web components and I'm trying to wrap my head around reusable styles in web components in general, and StencilJS in particular. As a developer, I'm naturally lazy and don't want to think about focus state, fading animations, etc. I want to use something that is already there and not reinvent the wheel.

If I understand correctly Stencil is mainly used as a base for framework independent components. As such, all components need a fair bit of styling. Since the shadow DOM encapsulates styles, every component is basically styled from scratch aside from some CSS variables that can be passed (`globalStyles` don't bleed into the shadow DOM, and the `part()` selector is it's own topic).

Even something simple like having global styles for an input field or button is hard to achieve. I've been looking into adding Tailwind CSS to my Stencil project but have been hitting some walls. All in all, it feels like I'm doing something unidiomatic when trying to add external CSS. It seems as though Stencil/web components are not meant to be styled this way and I'm fighting the tide.

Beyond the technical details, how should one think about styling web components in a scalable way? How do you share styles between them and avoid having to create lengthy and complex styles yourself?

I'm super happy about any help and input on this!

Comment: Like all who start the Web Components journey with a _tool_ , you fell in the shadowDOM trap. shadowDOM is **optional**. Learn Web Components like you learned HTML, learn the basics, build with the basics, only when you need to upscale do you select a _tool_

Comment: Shadow DOM is optional, but very often the right choice depending on what your component library aims to achieve. It is itself also a tool that can be used or not, according to your needs. You will need to figure out if it is the right choice, but don't assume it isn't just because it's optional - there are pros and cons to both using shadow DOM and not using it.

Comment: In my case it is the shadow DOM is absolutely required. This will be code other people will embed on their websites and the style encapsulation is on of the biggest advantages for me in this case (oc accounting for some weird cases where the encapsulation breaks). But I'd like to direct the attention back to the original question: What's the "right" way to style webcomponents?

Comment: There isn't any one single "right" way - see my answer.

Comment: Yeah, your answer is super helpful. I'm still digesting it and trying it out in my test app.

Comment: Also - if you are looking for something like a "reference implementation", see the Ionic framework project: https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-framework/tree/main/core. FTR, they are using a SASS based approach (quite complex) with most components using shadow DOM.

Answer (score 1):

The overall design of a solution will be entirely dependent on whether or not your components use shadow DOM. But whichever is the case, "sharing" style is relatively straightforward.

Stencil allows you to include a global style sheet as part of the library: https://stenciljs.com/docs/config#globalstyle. This is of relatively little use if you are using shadow DOM.

Sharing style when using shadow DOM is easily achieved through the use of SASS via the @stencil/sass plugin (see https://stenciljs.com/docs/plugins#stencil-plugins). You can include a "global" SASS file - with whatever SASS features you decide to use like sass variables, @mixin, @use, @extend etc. - through the Stencil config file which then lets you use any of the SASS in any component's SASS style file. For example:

```js
    plugins: [
        sass({
            injectGlobalPaths: [
                'src/global/_library-core.scss',
                'node_modules/some-sass-package/_main.scss'
            ]
        })
    ],
```

Another option is to use CSS custom properties, which can be defined in the library's global style sheet. This could be done on it's own or in conjunction with SASS. Custom properties are usually used as a solution for allowing external style configuration such as global theming rather than for "sharing" style within the library, but would be a valid choice for this as well.

You could also stick with plain CSS and use @import to pull in shared CSS files from your project. For example you could define styling for all `<input>` elements in a shared file "common_input.css and @import that into component style sheets where necessary. This approach is probably more challenging to do successfully and less flexible than a SASS approach.